# How to Import Classes and Files across file structure; __init__.py confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I can't figure out these imports. I've got all but 1 working at the deepest level in the file structure.

File structure is:

```
| rootDir
|--- file1.py (main.py)
|--- appDir
|------ schema1Dir
|--------- file2.py (etlProcess.py)
|--------- file3.py (recordTable.py)
|------ schema2Dir
|--------- ... 
|------ ...
```

Where I'm stuck:

file2.py is trying to import file3.py from the same directory in order to trigger a class in that file. I'm getting an error that there is.

> No module named 'file3'

I've tried including `__init__.py` files in every directory, removing those files completely, only putting those files in certain directories, etc. All solutions I've found in my Google searches, but I can't get this to work.

Here's a screenshot of VS Code that might visualize this better..

[image]

Comment: I didn’t try to read the screenshot, but from the error message I conclude that you need to use `import file3`, not `import file3.py`.

Comment: Also, I've tried importing the class as 'from recordTable import facilities', and I get the same error

Comment: I didn't call it with .py, wish i did though haha

Comment: Then what you have written was not actually what the error message was. Please include the exact error message with traceback (as text, not a screenshot).

Comment: fixed the error to remove ".py"

Comment: You have no file or module with that name. I‘m giving up now. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python imports are always relative to the directory where the Python interpreter is run, which in your case is the source root at `~/projects/companynurse/busterEtl`, so in order for `etlProcess.py` to import `recordTable.py`, it should either use absolute import with the full package path:

```
from application.facilities import recordTable
```

or use [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) with a `.` to explicitly locate `recordTable.py` in the same directory:

```
from . import recordTable
```

Comment: when using the first solution I get "attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

the second says 

import .recordTable
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @TimHalbert: The second (post-edit) is definitely legal syntax, unless your IDE is so old it's trying to run the code with some pre-2.7 version of Python (pre-edit it was wrong). The former should work *if* your package is actually installed somewhere, or your working directory is actually the directory that contains `application`, but it won't work right if you're just running Python willy-nilly inside your dev tree.

Comment: @blhsing: `__init__.py` is not required at all in Python 3 thanks to [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), and in fact, if there is no meaningful code to put in it, you're encouraged not to do so, leaving it a namespace package (so separate installs can share the namespace easily without needing explicit workarounds in `__init__.py` in both packages to enable it). About the only thing that relies on it is `setuptools.find_packages`, but that's why they've since introduced `setuptools.find_namespace_packages`, to find directories with Python files with or without `__init__.py`.

Comment: Ok I got the error to change completely now, not sure if proper SO etiquette is to continue it here, or not

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ah I was not aware of this change in Python 3.3. Thanks.

Comment: @TimHalbert: Try to solve the new error for a little bit yourself (it's the best way to learn); if you can't, ask a *new* question, leaving this one alone (changing a question after it's been adequately answered makes the existing answers useless to future askers).

Comment: NOTE that the relative path works, but VS Code shows it as an error, the first solution works completely, my error moved to a function that is called from inside the recordTable file now